# Ricean Multipath channel model implementation

Tags: python, ofdm, multipath

I'm trying to implement a multipath ricean channel model. I had found several resources but I'm kind of lost with too much information. What I have from now is the following step:

```
1- Generate the signal without noise/channel
2- convolve with the channel response 
3- add white gaussian noise
```

My problem is how to generate the channel response? As far as I understand I have to generate a ricean distributed filter with ntaps, where each tap represent one path.

The transmitted data is a series of OFDM symbols for a BERxSNR plot.

The channel model is Ricean with multipath and doppler shift. From my references I have all the parameters but I didn't understand how to transform this into an algorithm.

### update

```
def generate_rician(self,K,data):
    self.__rician_mu  = sqrt(K/(K+1))
    self.__rician_s   = sqrt(1/(2*(K+1)))
    self.__rician_chn = self.__rician_s*(random.standard_normal((data_size,)) + random.standard_normal((data_size,))*1j) + self.__rician_mu
    return self.__rician_chn*data + wgn
```

Where wgn is the white gaussian noise, omitted here. I have to improve this code adding doppler spread and multipath

[edited]
The above code try to reflect the following equations:
$$
C = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2*(K+1)}}*(X+j*Y) + \sqrt{\frac{K}{K+1}}$$

$$
R = TxC + N
$$

Where $T$ is the transmited signal(QPSK-OFDM), $N$ is the white gaussian noise, $X$ and $Y$ are two pseudo random variables with normal distrubution. $K$ is the ricean factor.

As a reference the equation used as theoretical reference is:

$$
Pb = \frac{1}{2} {\rm erfc} \left (\sqrt{\frac{K*EbN0}{K + EbN0}}  \right)
$$

An output of my system simulation:

[image: Rician fading simulation]

As you can see my results are divergent from the theoretical. The simulation was done using scipy fftpack and the code above.

In green you see the theoretical AWGN BER curve, in blue theoretical rician fadin K=5 and in red the results from my simulated system.

Comment: You don't need the "channel response" unless you are looking to construct the signal as it will appear at the receiving antenna. More commonly, people use
the model to simulate the sample values at the output of matched filters, in which case transmitting complex number $c$ results in output $c(\rho+X)+N$ where $\rho$ is the channel gain, and $X$ and $N$ are complex (zero-mean) Gaussian random variables. Note that $X$ is essentially Rayleigh fading.  A bigger issue is what correlation, if any, you want to assume between the gains $\rho_i$ and the fading $X_i$ in the various OFDM samples.

Comment: Ok. This model I had done and tested against theoretical results and my results agree, but, what about multipath?

Comment: The model Dilip showed already includes multi-path.

Comment: May I miss something. I'm updating the question with the code I have so far.

Comment: @EuripedesRochaFilho The standard Rician channel model considers the received signal to have arrived over two paths, one a direct (usually line-of-site) path or specular reflection which has lots of energy and the other being the net result of a whole host of paths each having very little energy but with very similar (non-resolvable) delays. Via the central limit theorem of probability this gives the Gaussian $X$ in my comment (same as Rayleigh fading) while the direct path gives $\rho$. If there are multiple specular paths that are resolvable by the receiver, more tricks can be played.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, so I have to change the model to place the gain $\rho$? and How apply doppler? I'll update the question to reflect the equation I'm using.

Comment: Not sure how relevant they are, but [the animation on this page is a nice representation of why what you have already includes (non-specular) multipath](http://www.wirelesscommunication.nl/reference/chaptr03/ricepdf/rice.htm) and [this page from the Mathworks has a nice explanation of a more detailed approach, that includes Doppler.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/fading-channels.html#bq5zk36)

Comment: Sorry, I'll improve the text @PeterK.

Comment: So, I still not happy with my understanding of this subject. I'm generating a set of gains and applying then to ofdm my signal. But why I'm not getting the same curve as in the theoretical result?

Comment: You said you want to have a multipath channel. This probably means that you want to generate a frequency selective channel realization (i.e. with an impulse response longer than one tap). You are not doing this right now. You are drawing from your rician distribution once for every data symbol. That is, each symbol sees a different frequency-flat rician channel. This is probably not correct.

You said that you have the channel parameters for the different taps. Could you post them, please?

Comment: @jan I have channel parameters like max doppler, ricean K factor and etc. And yes, I'm trying to apply a frequency selective channel.